# Yii2 - NavBar widget hyperlink to div

Tags: html, hyperlink, navbar, yii2

anyone knows how can i in Yii2 using the navbar widget make a hyperlink to a div that is above the 100% height screen and is hidden in order that the screen scrolls down to it?

The code i'm using for the navbar is the standard one that comes with yii in layout.php

```
['label' => 'Contact', 'url' => ['/site/contact']],
```

**I substitute 'url' => ['/site/contact']], --> by something like 'url' => ['#divid']],**

But it doesn't works.

Many thanks in advance for an answer.

Comment: And can you elaborate the significance of doing so ?

Comment: I think i'm not following the question, but i'l give it a try to explain what i need. I nav bar of bootstrap 3 widget for Yii2 i need to click on an hyperlink and the site must scrolls down to a div with a certain id. In html it is very easy to do, but in Yii2 i'm not able to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just specify `url` as a string:

```
['label' => 'Contact', 'url' => '#divId'],
```

`Url` parameter is processed by [Url::to()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-baseurl.html#to%28%29-detail) method, you can see there how string is interpreted:

> a normal string: it will be returned as is.

Comment: Many thanks for the answer, but i made: 'label' => 'Contactos', Url::toRoute(['site/index', '#' => 'contactos'])],        and it does nothing, although the illegal offset error is gone.

Comment: Just add it exactly as I wrote.

Comment: SOLVED. I think i have tried that way the first time, but now it is working. Thank's a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for your help, it works. I was trying to do this

```
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#navbar" data-offset="50">
<?php $this->beginBody() ?>

<div class="wrap">
<?php
NavBar::begin([
    //'brandLabel' => Yii::$app->name,
    'brandLabel' => '<img src="SLOGAN.png" style="display:inline; vertical-align:top; margin-top:20px; margin-left: 10px;"/>',
    'brandUrl' => Yii::$app->homeUrl,
    'options' => [
        'class' => 'navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse',
        'id'=>'navbar'
    ],
]);
echo Nav::widget([
    'options' => ['class' => 'nav navbar-nav navbar-left'],
    'items' => [
        ['label' => 'HOME', 'url' => '#section1'],
        ['label' => 'ABOUT', 'url' => '#section2'],
        ['label' => 'SERVICES', 'url' =>'#section3'],
        ['label' => 'FAQS', 'url' => '#section4'],
        ['label' => 'CONTACTS', 'url' => '#section5'],
```